# Tikz picture contains overlaps of objects and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new at using the TikZ package to make commutative diagrams. I'm trying to draw a triangle with an arrow between each pair of objects. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (Q) {$\QQ$};
  \node (tQ) [below of=Q] {$\QQ\otimes\QQ$};
  \node (cQ) [right of=tQ] {$\QQ\times\QQ$};
  \draw[->] (Q) to node {$i$} (cQ);
  \draw[->] (tQ) to node [swap] {$m$} (Q);
  \draw[<-] (cQ) to node [swap] {$\iota$} (tQ);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(`\QQ` is a command I've defined to produce `\mathbb{Q}`, since it saves me typing.) The diagram compiles fine, but the objects and arrows overlap quite badly on the bottom line: the right- and left-most `\mathbb{Q}` in the nodes on the bottom line touch, and the arrow is superimposed over them. How can I fix this so that the diagram can be more readable?

Comment: The easiest way out is to add `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]`. But this would affect all nodes in that particular TikZ picture placed by `to` command. See the `positioning` library in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot- the nodes are now readable. If you make that an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way out is to add `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]`. But this would affect all nodes in that particular TikZ picture placed by to command.

For more specific solutions, the `positioning` library is a very powerful tool. (see page 185 in the manual v2.10)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the positioning tikzlibrary and the above or right

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (Q) {$\QQ$};
  \node (tQ) [below =5em of Q] {$\QQ\otimes\QQ$};
  \node (cQ) [right =5em of tQ] {$\QQ\times\QQ$};
  \draw[->] (Q) to node[ above] {$i$} (cQ);
  \draw[->] (tQ) to node [right] {$m$} (Q);
  \draw[<-] (cQ) to node [above] {$\iota$} (tQ);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```